# Using url segments to display content

Tags: segments, entryid, newsletter

I am building a newsletter template that will display between 5 and 7 articles. My client will get to choose which articles will display by putting the entry_id's in the url (ex. http://site.com/newsletter/111/222/333/444/555/666). How can I do this? Also, I am using an older verion of EE (hence the use of 'weblog'). Below is my code, which only works if there's 1 article (ex. http://site.com/newsletter/111)

```
{if segment_1 != "" }

{exp:weblog:entries entry_id="{segment_1}" limit="1" dynamic="no" disable="member_data|pagination|categories"}

            <tr>
                <td valign="top" width="150">
                    {if image != ""}<a href="{url_title_path="/article"}" alt="{title}" title="{title}" target="_blank">{image}</a>{/if}
                </td>
                <td valign="top" width="14"></td>
                <td valign="top" width="380">
                            <a href="{url_title_path="/article"}" alt="View {title}" title="View {title}" target="_blank">{title}</a>
                            <br /><br />
                            {if alt_summary != ""}
                                {exp:strip_p}{alt_summary}{/exp:strip_p}
                            {if:else}
                                {exp:strip_p}{summary}{/exp:strip_p}
                            {/if}
                </td>
            </tr>
{/exp:weblog:entries}

{/if}

{if segment_2 != "" }

{exp:weblog:entries entry_id="{segment_2}" limit="1" dynamic="no" disable="member_data|pagination|categories"}

            <tr>
                <td valign="top" width="150">
                    {if image != ""}<a href="{url_title_path="/article"}" alt="{title}" title="{title}" target="_blank">{image}</a>{/if}
                </td>
                <td valign="top" width="14"></td>
                <td valign="top" width="380">
                            <a href="{url_title_path="/article"}" alt="View {title}" title="View {title}" target="_blank">{title}</a>
                            <br /><br />
                            {if alt_summary != ""}
                                {exp:strip_p}{alt_summary}{/exp:strip_p}
                            {if:else}
                                {exp:strip_p}{summary}{/exp:strip_p}
                            {/if}
                </td>
            </tr>

{/exp:weblog:entries}

{/if}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that the above code is embedded, so it apeears on the page <table>(the code)</table>

Answer (score 1):

I never used EECMS 1, but I gonna try to help you.

There are some errors on your code.

- The `segment_1` is always `newsletter`. You never could use it on `{exp:weblog:entries entry_id="{segment_1}" [...]`;
- if your second conditional evaluates as true, both your conditionals will evaluate, because you need a `segment_1` to have a `segment_2`;
- if both codes are the same, you don't need two conditionals;
- if you want to pass more than one `id`, you can't use the `limit` parameter;
- EECMS 1 used `on` and `off` as parameter values; not `yes` and `no`;
- `trackbacks` was also a possible value for the `disable` parameter on EECMS 1.

  Why not `http://site.com/newsletter/111|222|333|444|555|666`?

You could use:

```
{if segment_2 != "" }

    {exp:weblog:entries entry_id="{segment_2}" dynamic="off" disable="categories|custom_fields|member_data|pagination|trackbacks"}

        <tr>
            <td valign="top" width="150">
                {if image != ""}<a href="{url_title_path="/article"}" alt="{title}" title="{title}" target="_blank">{image}</a>{/if}
            </td>
            <td valign="top" width="14"></td>
            <td valign="top" width="380">
                        <a href="{url_title_path="/article"}" alt="View {title}" title="View {title}" target="_blank">{title}</a>
                        <br /><br />
                        {if alt_summary != ""}
                            {exp:strip_p}{alt_summary}{/exp:strip_p}
                        {if:else}
                            {exp:strip_p}{summary}{/exp:strip_p}
                        {/if}
            </td>
        </tr>
    {/exp:weblog:entries}

{/if}
```

Even better, you could put the conditional around the embed, to prevent its parsing:

```
{if segment_2 != "" }
    {embed="newsletter/articles"}
{/if}
```

I hope it helps.